# Why case class used as key in reduceByKey doesn't work in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use a case class for key in a rdd and then reduceByKey using the case class. But when a tuple is used it is working fine.

```
case class Employee(id: Int, name: String)

val e1 = Employee(1,"chan")
val e2 = Employee(1,"joey")

val salary = Array((e1,100),(e2,1100),(e1,190),(e2,110))

val salaryRDD = sc.parallelize(salary)
salaryRDD.reduceByKey(_+_).collect
```

Output:

```
 res1: Array[(Employee, Int)] = Array((Employee(1,chan),100),
  Employee(1,chan),190), (Employee(1,joey),1100), (Employee(1,joey),110))
```

But When used with tuples this works fine.

```
val t1 = (1,"chan")
val t2 = (1,"joey")
val salary2 = Array((t1,100),(t2,1100),(t1,190),(t2,110))
val salaryRDD2 = sc.parallelize(salary2)
salaryRDD2.reduceByKey(_+_).collect
```

Output:

```
res2: Array[((Int, String), Int)] = Array(((1,chan),290), ((1,joey),1210))
```

The hashCode and equals works well in case class.

```
scala> val em1 = Employee(1,"chan")
em1: Employee = Employee(1,chan)

scala> val em2 = Employee(1,"chan")
em2: Employee = Employee(1,chan)

scala> em1 == em2
res5: Boolean = true

scala> em1.hashCode
res6: Int = 545142355

scala> em2.hashCode
res7: Int = 545142355
```

Why is this behaviour ? How to make case class to work with reduceByKey ?

Comment: very odd - your Spark code works perfectly fine for me (getting the expected result) - which Spark version are you using?

Comment: I am using spark-1.6.2

Comment: me too :O sorry, I have no other ideas...

Comment: Tested with Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.0 on Databricks cloud, in both versions I have the same issue as author. @TzachZohar Have you compiled Spark or downloaded official distribution?

Comment: I'm using the official distribution.

Comment: @TzachZohar And do you use REPL (spark-shell)?

Comment: @T.Gawęda This is a known spark-shell bug.

Comment: That's make sense - I was using Zeppelin and Databricks notes and they work in the same way as REPL

Comment: @T.Gawęda Yup, any interactive environment which depends on spark shell internals will do the same. The bad part is that it depends on the data distribution so it is close to non-deterministic. from the user perspective.